# C# Асинхронный TCP сервер, как держать соединение?

Tags: c#, tcp

Хочу чтобы TCP сервер держал постоянное соединение с клиентом. Сейчас он после подключения клиента получает одно сообщение отправляет один ответ и больше ничего не принимает от клиента.

Код:

```
using Server.Models;
using Server.Models.HTTP;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;

namespace Server {

  public class Server {

    private readonly int m_numConnections;   
    private readonly int m_receiveBufferSize;
    BufferManager m_bufferManager; 
    const int opsToPreAlloc = 2;
    Socket listenSocket;     
    SocketAsyncEventArgsPool m_readWritePool;
    int m_totalBytesRead;       
    int m_numConnectedSockets;      
    Semaphore m_maxNumberAcceptedClients;

    public Server(int numConnections, int receiveBufferSize) {
        m_totalBytesRead = 0;
        m_numConnectedSockets = 0;
        m_numConnections = numConnections;
        m_receiveBufferSize = receiveBufferSize;
        m_bufferManager = new BufferManager(receiveBufferSize * numConnections * opsToPreAlloc,
                receiveBufferSize);
        m_readWritePool = new SocketAsyncEventArgsPool(numConnections);
        m_maxNumberAcceptedClients = new Semaphore(numConnections, numConnections);
    }

    public void Init() {
        m_bufferManager.InitBuffer();
        SocketAsyncEventArgs readWriteEventArg;
        for (int i = 0; i < m_numConnections; i++) {
            readWriteEventArg = new SocketAsyncEventArgs();
            readWriteEventArg.Completed += new EventHandler<SocketAsyncEventArgs>(IO_Completed);
            readWriteEventArg.UserToken = new AsyncUserToken(); 
            m_bufferManager.SetBuffer(readWriteEventArg);
            m_readWritePool.Push(readWriteEventArg);
        }
    }

    public void Start(IPEndPoint localEndPoint) {
        listenSocket = new Socket(localEndPoint.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        listenSocket.Bind(localEndPoint);
        listenSocket.Listen(100);
        StartAccept(null);
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to terminate the server process....");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }


    public void StartAccept(SocketAsyncEventArgs acceptEventArg) {
        if(acceptEventArg == null) {
            acceptEventArg = new SocketAsyncEventArgs();
            acceptEventArg.Completed += new EventHandler<SocketAsyncEventArgs>(AcceptEventArg_Completed);
        }
        else {
            acceptEventArg.AcceptSocket = null;
        }

        m_maxNumberAcceptedClients.WaitOne();
        bool willRaiseEvent = listenSocket.AcceptAsync(acceptEventArg);
        if(!willRaiseEvent) {
            ProcessAccept(acceptEventArg);
        }
    }


    void AcceptEventArg_Completed(object sender, SocketAsyncEventArgs e) {
        ProcessAccept(e);
    }

    private void ProcessAccept(SocketAsyncEventArgs e) {
        Interlocked.Increment(ref m_numConnectedSockets);
        Console.WriteLine("Client connection accepted. There are {0} clients connected to the server",
                m_numConnectedSockets);
        SocketAsyncEventArgs readEventArgs = m_readWritePool.Pop();
        ((AsyncUserToken)readEventArgs.UserToken).Socket = e.AcceptSocket;

        bool willRaiseEvent = e.AcceptSocket.ReceiveAsync(readEventArgs);
        if(!willRaiseEvent) {
            ProcessReceive(readEventArgs);
        }
        StartAccept(e);
    }


    void IO_Completed(object sender, SocketAsyncEventArgs e) {
        switch(e.LastOperation) {
            case SocketAsyncOperation.Receive:
                ProcessReceive(e);
                break;
            case SocketAsyncOperation.Send:
                ProcessSend(e);
                break;
            default:
                throw new ArgumentException("The last operation completed on the socket was not a receive or send");
        }
    }

    public bool HasMethod(object objectToCheck, string methodName) {
        var type = objectToCheck.GetType();
        return type.GetMethod(methodName) != null;
    }

    private void ProcessReceive(SocketAsyncEventArgs e) {
        AsyncUserToken token = (AsyncUserToken)e.UserToken;
        if (e.BytesTransferred > 0 && e.SocketError == SocketError.Success) {
            Interlocked.Add(ref m_totalBytesRead, e.BytesTransferred);
            e.SetBuffer(e.Offset, e.BytesTransferred);

            bool willRaiseEvent = token.Socket.SendAsync(e);
            if(!willRaiseEvent) {
                ProcessSend(e);
            }           
        }
    }




    private void ProcessSend(SocketAsyncEventArgs e) {
        if (e.SocketError == SocketError.Success) {
            AsyncUserToken token = (AsyncUserToken)e.UserToken;
            bool willRaiseEvent = token.Socket.ReceiveAsync(e);
            if (!willRaiseEvent)
            {
                ProcessReceive(e);
            }

        }
        else
        {
            CloseClientSocket(e);
        }
    }

    private void CloseClientSocket(SocketAsyncEventArgs e) {
        AsyncUserToken token = e.UserToken as AsyncUserToken;

        try {
            token.Socket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Send);
        }
        catch (Exception) { }
        token.Socket.Close();

        Interlocked.Decrement(ref m_numConnectedSockets);

        m_readWritePool.Push(e);

        m_maxNumberAcceptedClients.Release();
        Console.WriteLine("A client has been disconnected from the server. There are {0} clients connected to the server", m_numConnectedSockets);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: `когда я убираю CloseSocket` - этого метода нет в вашем коде